# Remove/Add nvidia drivers ubuntu 14.04.2

Tags: drivers, nvidia, ubuntu-drivers, nvidia-prime

I'm following [Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/HybridGraphics#A14.04) to install the drivers for hybrid-graphics in Ubuntu 14.04.2.

Here are the steps:

NVIDIA systems:

1. Make sure that no other NVIDIA driver is installed (keep the
   nvidia-common package).
2. Install nvidia-331.
3. Reboot the system (restarting X won't be enough).

   NOTE: you can easily switch between GPUs from the Prime section of the nvidia-settings panel.

I'm not sure about step 1 - is it ok to just go to Additional Drivers and select nvidia-331 , will this uninstall other nvidia drivers if I have any ? And I guess this should install the driver (step 2) , or I have to do something explicitly like install from command line ?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly,

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia*
```

Enable the Universe and Multiverse repositories - you need to do this to allow the bumblebee and nvidia packages respectively to be installed. Then:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia primus linux-headers-generic

sudo reboot
```

To run your application with the discrete NVIDIA card run in the terminal:

```
optirun [options] <application> [application-parameters]
```

Example:

```
optirun firefox
```

For a list of options for optirun run:

```
optirun --help
```

You can also use `prime-select` option e.g.

```
sudo prime-select nvidia

sudo prime-select intel
```

To check:

```
prime-select --query
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers) topic.

I've found there everything what I needed once.